# Angular 2 modal popup over 100% height and scrolling, unfriendly UX

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using these nice little modal popups for my Angular 2 single page application so that it doesn't leave the main page but shows the user more content. They float above the main content sort of shading the background with a bit of opacity and can be closed out of with a close button. The problem I am having is that if they overflow the full browser window on any size device they cannot be seen unless I add overflow: auto; and then it adds a secondary scroll bar which is terrible to use. If you dont click the second scroll bar specifically it will just scroll the background. Is there a way around this?

```
<div style="z-index: 9999; float-offset: 50%; position: fixed;" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
     [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">   
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 single-item-modal">
          <!-- content goes here--> 
    <a [routerLink]="['/']"><div (click)="hide()"><img src="../assets/img/we.png"/></div></a>




.modal {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

Comment: Set `overflow: hidden;` to the `body` when the modal is open

Comment: The modal is a <router-outlet> angular 2 component and it is part of the body so when I do that it locks the modal also

Comment: I did an onclick for opening the modal: let b = document.getElementById('bod');
    b.style.overflow = 'hidden'; It causes the model to not scroll even though I set the modals scroll to auto or to scroll using overflow-y and overflow. It also breaks my close button too for some reason.

Comment: nevermind I found the bug lol, thanks